# Juju - agent-state pending

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.2, my juju environment is MaaS and have juju installed on the same server. Have 3 nodes. After I did:

juju deploy --repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/mysql
juju deploy --repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress

I got the 2 nodes allocated to root and I waited 1 hour and the agent-state is still pending, how do I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the MAAS logs, I think something is wrong over there. Also, looks like you are not running the latest MAAS, and it also helps to run the latest juju:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/stable
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # (or selectively install juju-core and maas packages)